# SQL query in PHP script keeps "losing" one row

Tags: php, mysql

Let's assume I have a table like this:

```
+------+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|   id |  tstamp |   product_id |        name | configuration |
+------+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|   3  |      15 |           02 |        bike |        abc    |
|   2  |      16 |           03 |        car  |        dfg    |
|   1  |      11 |           04 |        tree |        ehg    |
+------+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

When I run a simple query like

```
SELECT id, tstamp, product_id, name, configuration
FROM tl_iso_product_collection_item
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

It returns 3 rows. As expected. Works, right? BUT, if I implement this query into a PHP script and try to fetch rows, theres always ONE missing. Always. Even in the most simple query. Where did I make a mistake?

Script looks like this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db');

mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

$query = "SELECT id, tstamp, product_id, name, configuration
    FROM table
    ORDER BY `id` DESC "

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
echo $row[4];
}

mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
```

This will result in displaying only 2 out of 3 rows. My question is, why tho? If I insert the query above directly into phpmyadmin it shows 3 results, not 2. What is wrong here? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing a semi-colon after the $query definition btw

Comment: As a side-hint, you'll help yourself by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row` as then you can access e.g. `$row['product_id']`

Comment: Can you paste your actual output? You have a different table name in code to the query you ran in CLI above.

Comment: I tried with your code ( slight amendment to account for db table etc ) and it produced all the records expected.

Comment: You didn't INSERT a row in an uncommited transaction in phpmyadmin?Definitely the same db?

Comment: Didn't want to post the whole thing, but my code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Q8iDA4qK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fetch_allgemein = mysqli_fetch_array($result_allgemein);
$fetch_configuration = mysqli_fetch_array($result_configuration);
```

You are fetching the first record for each query result here already – so the internal “pointer” to the current record gets advanced to the second record in each result set, and therefor when you loop over the result using

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_allgemein)) {
```

later on, the first record is of course omitted.

You will need to reset the “pointer” using [`mysqli_result::data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) if you want to get *all* records in your loops after you’ve already fetched the first record each.

Comment: I was wondering, after going trough all lines again, why I even had those two lines, eventough I didn't even use them. Deleting those 2 lines worked for me. But thanks, I'll keep your solution in mind!